# Keygen/crack/malware detected as virus only after unzipping

Tags: virus, zip, malware, anti-virus

I'm wondering how come a keygen/crack are not detected as virus when it is inside a compressed folder. Only after the unzipping the antivirus detects it as a threat.

Comment: Is the Zip file password protected? Maybe the antivirus program is configured to check only executable files?

Comment: Sounds like a limitation of your security software.  My security software (Windows Defender) flags my compressed files all the time that contain executables it doesn’t like.  If you are worried you should use different security software

Comment: Antivirus software should detect a virus once a zip file is opened, not just when a file is extracted from a zip file. It looks like your antivirus software is incompetent. Windows Defender Antivirus and Comodo Internet Security can detect viruses inside zip files.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the difficulties of hosting files in the past such stuff was typically highly compressed and encrypted. Encryption prevented certain search routines to succeed.

An encrypted zipped file cannot be analysed because it compressed, it is unreadable.
Therefore fingerprint matching or disassembling and searching for malicious system calls won't work.

Furthermore,
if I sent you such a zip file as an attachment stating:

Dear Gennaro,
the key is the key!

You would understand how to unpack the archive.
The antivirus engine would not be able to interpret that.

Comment: But most "antivirus" software have been able to look inside zip archives since early 2000s...

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I left out an important attribute  :)

Comment: There a handful of compression algorithms today, most security software, has no problem extracting the files temporarily or just simply viewing the contents

Comment: Hello @r2d3 thank you very much for your reply

Comment: Gennaro, I am very happy to hear that the reply fits your needs. :)